# Triangle in hexagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

```
In a regular hexagon ABCDEF is the midpoint (G)of the sides FE  and S
intersection of lines AC and GB.
```

[image]

**(a)** What is the relationship shared point of straight line with GB?

```
AB=a 
BC=b
```

> 1. BS = αBG = α(-2a+ 2/3b)
> 2. BS = -a + ΨAC= -a + Ψ(a+b)
> 3. BS=-4/7a + 3/7b

**(b)** What proportion of the area of ​​the regular hexagon ABCDEF a surface area of
triangle ABS?

How can i calculate ABS triangle and ABCDEF hexagon ? Thanks

Comment: How should *we* know if is your answer? What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I've removed the 'linear algebra' tag. May I recommend that you read the description of a tag before you select it? Also, your first question is pretty much unintelligible. Are you trying to find the ratio BS:BG?

Comment: The problem statement is unclear and does not match the picture. In the picture, G is the midpoint of DF, and the hexagon is ABCEFD. In part A, are you being asked for the relationship between two things? Finally, a regular hexagon has equal sides and angles, so is composed of 6 equilateral triangles and can be parametrized by $e^{in\pi/6}$ or $(\cos\frac{in\pi}6,\sin\frac{in\pi}6)$ for $0\le n<6$.

Comment: "linear algebra" is an appropriate tag. Question (a) is about vectors: With $\mathbf{a} := \vec{AB}$ and $\mathbf{b} := \vec{BC}$, what is $\vec{BS}$ in terms of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$? Options 1 and 2 describe approaches to the answer: (1) $\vec{BS} = \alpha \vec{BG}$, where we can write $\vec{BG} = -2\mathbf{a} + 3/2\mathbf{b}$ (OP has typo) and $\alpha$ happens to be $2/7$. (2) $\vec{BS}$ decomposes as $-\vec{AB} + \phi \vec{AC} = - \mathbf{a} + \phi(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})$, where $\phi$ happens to be $3/7$. So, from either of these, (3) $\vec{BS} = -4/7\mathbf{a} + 3/7\mathbf{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment to an answer ...

I'll re-state the question.

> (a) With vectors $\mathbf{a} := \vec{AB}$ and $\mathbf{b} := \vec{BC}$, how do we write $\vec{BS}$ in terms of $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$?

OP lists three relations. I believe the the first two are approaches to finding the final, third, relation.

1. $\vec{BS} = \alpha \vec{BG}$, where we can write $\vec{BG} = -2\mathbf{a} + \frac{3}{2}\mathbf{b}$ (OP has typo) and scalar $\alpha$ happens to be $\frac{2}{7}$ (as explained below).
2. $\vec{BS}$ decomposes as $-\vec{AB} + \phi \vec{AC} = - \mathbf{a} + \phi(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})$, where scalar $\phi$ happens to be $3/7$.
3. So, from either of the above,
   $$\vec{BS} = \frac{2}{7}\left(-2\mathbf{a}+\frac{3}{2}\mathbf{b}\right) = -\mathbf{a} + \frac{3}{7}\left(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b}\right) = -\frac{4}{7}\mathbf{a} +\frac{3}{7}\mathbf{b}$$

To see that $\alpha = 2/7$ in (1), tilt the diagram and construct segment $GP$ parallel to segment $DA$, with $P$ on the perpendicular dropped from $B$ to $DA$. Decompose the bottom half of the hexagon into equilateral triangles, and note that vertical lines through the vertices break these into congruent 30-60-90 triangles.

[image]

As $G$ is the midpoint of a side of these triangles, and $GP$ is parallel to their short legs, $GP$ cuts through midpoints all the way across, and is cut into 7 congruent segments. Note that $BS : BG = PQ : PG = 2 : 7$, so that $\vec{BS} = \frac{2}{7}\vec{BG}$.

To determine that $\phi=3/7$ in (2) ... well ... I just worked backwards from (3), but there's probably a nice geometric explanation here, too.

Moving on ...

> (b) What is the proportion of the area of the hexagon to the area of $ABS$?

Note that $\triangle ABR$, as one of those 30-60-90 triangles, makes up one-twelfth of the hexagon. Calling the hexagon's area $H$, we can write

$$\frac{H}{\triangle ABS} = \frac{12 \triangle ABR}{\triangle ABS} = \frac{12 \cdot \frac{1}{2} |BR| |AR|}{\frac{1}{2}|BR||AS|} = 12 \frac{|AR|}{|AS|} = 12\frac{\frac{1}{2}|AC|}{|AS|} = 6\frac{|AC|}{|AS|} = 6\frac{1}{\phi} = 14$$

Answer (score 1):

One can use the geometry. However, the point of the sketch below is to show that the problem can be solved *mechanically*.

We could let the sides of the regular hexagon be, say, $a$. However, it is easier, at least for typing, to choose a specific length. Then we can if necessary scale our answer. Sides $1$ are not a bad idea, but sides $4$ are more convenient, fewer fractions for a while.

Let the $x$-axis be along $AB$, wjth $A=(-2,0)$ and $B=(2,0)$. The coordinates of $C$ are now easy to find. They are $(2+4\cos(60^\circ), 4\sin(60^\circ))$, that is, $(4, 2\sqrt{3})$.

Now that we know the coordinates of $A$ and $C$, we can find the equation of line $AC$.

Do a similar calculation for the other side. The coordinates of $D$ are, by symmetry, $(-4, 2\sqrt{3})$. To get to $G$, we add $2\cos(60^\circ)$ to the $x$-coordinate, and $2\sin(60^\circ)$ to the $y$-coordinate. Thus $G$  has coordinates $(-3,3\sqrt{3})$.

Now that we know the coordinates of $B$ and $G$, we can find the equation of line $BG$.

To find the coordinates of $S$, find where our two lines with known equations meet.

Now that we know the coordinates of $S$, we can find answers to the questions. The only one that is clear is the asked ratio between the area of $\triangle ABS$ and the area of the hexagon. Each area can be computed. For example, the area of $\triangle ABS$ is one-half of $4$ times the $y$-coordinate of $S$.